# How to remove MySql apt repo

Tags: apt, uninstall, mysql

I was trying to install MySql on my system running Ubuntu 14.04. So I added a MySql apt from the link [Steps to fresh install MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#apt-repo-fresh-install).
After running into a lot of trouble and realizing apt uses libs not supported by Ubuntu 14.04, I was advised to remove the apt and use Ubuntu repo to install mysql.

However, it seems I can't find how to remove the above mentioned apt repo. I've been through some of the stuff I can find on the community but still no solution that worked for me! Software center shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/refaR.png).

Tried using `dpkg`, `aptitude -remove` also from software center but looks like I've hit a wall.
So any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` and  remove /etc/apt/sources.list and do `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: @mnstalemate "remove /etc/apt/sources.list" ? Why that?

Comment: Yes, I did that, though I used 'mysql*' as the reg exp, just to be safe.

Comment: @A.B so that when you update your repositories again, you won't have any manually added repos in the sources.list file.

Comment: @mnstalemate
So, wouldn't that affect other manually added repos?

Comment: Yes. it will delete added repos. But you always can `sudo apt-get update` and then manually add repos you want. This, kind of refreshes the sources.list file.

Comment: okay, tried that again, and it worked.. Thank you @mnstalemate
However, some packages were still present, extremely persistent they were, used synaptic to remove those.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So I added a MySql apt from the link [Steps to fresh install MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/index.html#apt-repo-fresh-install)

When those are really the steps that you followed, then this is your solution.

Open a terminal and run this command if you want to remove all configurations:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config
```

Otherwise, this command is sufficient:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-apt-config
```

Comment: Done, no success.

Comment: @neo.one The repository is still displayed in Synaptic?

Comment: Yes, it is displayed in Synaptic

Comment: Execute this command and write the output into your question: `find /etc/apt/ -type f | xargs grep "repo.mysql.com"`

Answer (score 2):

I found that `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` had all the references to mysql repositories:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ find /etc/apt/ -type f | xargs grep "repo.mysql.com"
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-apt-config
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.7
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-tools
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:#deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-tools-preview
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list:deb-src http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ stretch mysql-5.7
```

So I decided to remove the mysql.list i the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory and finaly `sudo apt-get update` does not come with mysql repositories

Thanks every one here

Comment: I posted as new answer because of reputation sorry

Comment: Why is this not an answer? The last line is what the OP did to solve the issue.